# I have forgotten my Gmail account password

Tags: oneplus-3

I have forgotten my Gmail account password but logged in on my  android phone. Also it was managed by my college IT Department which don't exist any more.How can I reset my password?

Comment: when you said that your Gmail was managed by your college IT department which doesn't exit any more so there is no question of accessing it, whether you have a password or not. Please make me aware if I've understood something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover your Gmail account password by following these steps.

1. Login to your Gmail account with the last time remembered password.
2. Click on forgot password link.
3. You will be asked to enter your recovery email address and phone number.
4. Then you'll get a confirmation code on your entered email or phone number.
5. Then you'll be able to reset your new password.

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Account password is the same password you use for other Google products, like Gmail and YouTube. If you forgot your password and would like to reset it, follow instructions from [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/41078?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

While Gmail Sign Up process, Google does ask for contact number and additional email address. If you've provided any of these data then you can easily recover your password using [Forgot Password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/41078?hl=en) link.